# Program crash when dynamic array initialization is to be freed

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory-management

I am trying to use a Person array-pointer to directly initialize the array.

I succeeded using the `new` operator for each element in the initialization list. However, am confused because am thinking about freeing the memory used by the pointer since I used the `new` keyword.

Whenever I used the `delete [] pp`, the program crashed but its working just as pasted below.

Can anyone enlighten me about it?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<sstream>
using namespace std;
class Person
{
    string lastName;
    string firstName;
public:
    Person(string fname, string lname) : firstName(fname),lastName(lname)
    {
    }
    string output()
    {
        stringstream ostr;
        ostr<<firstName<<" "<<lastName;
        return ostr.str();
    }
};
int main()
{
    Person *pp[4] = {new Person("Yusuf","Tijjani"),new Person("Mubarak","Shettima"),new Person("Musty","Haruna"),new Person("Fatima","Suleiman")};
    for(int i =0;i<4;++i)
        cout<<pp[i]->output()<<endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to call delete on the things in the array, not the array itself.

Comment: What you really need is to stop using `new`.

Comment: Ok. I tried this line of code and it works, in freeing it.                            'for(int i=0;i<4;++i)
 delete pp[i];'                                                                                             its the same as what you suggested right? @ Neil Butterworth

Comment: How? The code doesn't compile without the new in the initialization. @juanchopanza

Comment: @Kinyo356 `Person pp[4] = {Person("Yusuf","Tijjani"), Person("Mubarak","Shettima"), Person("Musty","Haruna"), Person("Fatima","Suleiman")};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `pp` is a pointer to  a dynamic array then you can free memory this way as you did:

```
delete[] pp;
```

But in fact you declare an array of pointers not a pointer to a dynamic array:

```
Person *pp[4] = {...}; // this is an array of pointers not a pointer to a dynamic array
```

To free memory in this case you have to iterate over all elements and call delete on them:

```
for(int i(0); i < 4; i++)
    delete pp[i];
```

- if the pointers inside the array are pointers to arrays then you can free memory this way:

  ```
  for(int i(0); i < 4; i++)
      delete[] pp[i];
  ```

Answer (score 2):

- `Person (*pp)[4]` is a pointer to an array of 4 `Person`s.
- `Person *pp[4]` is an array of 4 pointers to `Person`.

Since `pp` is a local array of pointers, you can't `delete[]` it: it's on the stack.

Instead, you need to `delete` every instance of `Person`.

Comment: Actually OP needs to not dynamically allocate anything.